# Extend Auto Generated Typescript Interfaces

Tags: typescript, typelite

I am looking at an inherited typescript project and wanting to add some functionality to some of the interfaces (such as `ToString()` on an address model for example) to make them more than just a DTO.

The problem I have is that the interfaces are all automatically generated using TypeLite from our API. This means if I add a method to one of our interfaces, this method will get removed the next time the TypeLite process is run.

So in essence, I was wondering if it is possible to extend an interface in a separate file? Similar to an extension method in C#.

Alternatively, is there are better option that TypeLite as I don't really like the way everything is put into a single file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to augment interfaces in a separate file.  I don't know what the layout of your project is like, but something like this might work:

```
import { GeneratedInterface } from "./interfaceLocation";
declare module "./interfaceLocation" {
  interface GeneratedInterface {
    newMethod(param: string): number;
  }
}
```

If not, you can figure it out from the linked documentation above or post a more complete example.

Hope that helps; good luck!